# why predicator behaves different when being used with for_each and remove_if

Tags: c++, stl

I have the following code, which calls `for_each` and `remove_if` function:

```
class Predicate 
{
  size_t timesCalled;
  
public:
  Predicate() : timesCalled(0) 
  {
  }

  bool operator()(const int &) 
  {
      std::cout<< "timesCalled:" << timesCalled << std::endl;
      ++timesCalled;
      return timesCalled == 1;
  }
};
```

This above is the predicator class;

```
void erase(std::vector<int>& v)
{
    auto f = Predicate();
    auto ss = for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), f);
    std::cout <<"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" << endl;

    auto end = std::remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(), f);
    for_each(v.begin(), v.end(),[](auto it)
    {
        std::cout<< it <<" :"  << std::endl;//(, i + 1);
    });
    std::cout <<"---------" << endl;
}

int main() { 
    std::vector<int> vec{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
}
```

the output of this program is :

```
timesCalled:0
timesCalled:1
timesCalled:2
timesCalled:3
timesCalled:4
timesCalled:5
timesCalled:6
timesCalled:7
timesCalled:8
timesCalled:9
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
timesCalled:0
timesCalled:0
timesCalled:1
timesCalled:2
timesCalled:3
timesCalled:4
timesCalled:5
timesCalled:6
timesCalled:7
timesCalled:8
```

why the `timescalled` value is different when I call `for_each` or call `remove_if`?
according to the `remove_if` pseudo code:

```
template <class ForwardIterator, class UnaryPredicate>
  ForwardIterator remove_if (ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last,
                             UnaryPredicate pred)
{
  ForwardIterator result = first;
  while (first!=last) {
    if (!pred(*first)) {
      if (result!=first)
        *result = std::move(*first);
      ++result;
    }
    ++first;
  }
  return result;
}
```

Both algorithms call `pred` one by one.

Comment: Look at [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove). `remove_if` uses `find_if` which uses **a copy** of `unaryPredicate`. So original passed predicate is not affected in first query - by `find_if`, that is why you get 0 twice.

Comment: Mutable predicates are not guaranteed to be compatible with the standard library. Try passing `std::ref(f)` instead.